Landscape-oriented longtable but in portrait mode
I have read this page but to no avail: Landscape-oriented table over multiple pages since the pages are made landscape alongside the tables.
Essentially, I would like to create a landscape table spanning multiple pages, whilst keeping all the pages themselves in portrait mode. Is there a way to do this?

if I understand the question that is exactly what lscape package is designed to do. just wrap the longtable in a landscape enviornment. If that is not what you want make a small complete example and describe how the desired output differs from the output you get

@DavidCarlisle I use the same code in Overleaf but the PDF outputted landscape tables with the pages in landscape mode as well (all other pages without landscape tables were portrait). I would like to have all the pages in portrait mode, without the need to rotate the PDF after it has been created.

it's an artifact of the viewer showing the page so the text is more readable, it doesn't for example affect what happens if you print the pdf.

That longtable, which span  several pages, should be inserted in landscape environment. sidewaystable (or sidwaysfigure) is intended for use for tables or images which occupy only one page.
An example:
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
   \begin{landscape}
      \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.75\linewidth}|c|}
         \hline
\lipsum[1] & 1 \\
\lipsum[2] & 2 \\
\lipsum[3] & 3 \\
\lipsum[4] & 4 \\
\lipsum[5] & 5 \\
          \hline
      \end{longtable}
   \end{landscape}
\end{document} 

In above MWE I didn't bother with table caption and types for column headers.

At use of landscape table be aware, that it always start new page.
